# ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, browser

more often than not, I get a list of ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE errors when loading a web page in google chrome - this results in assets not being loaded, images, style sheets etc.

what would be the cause of this? I have tried disabling browser extensions, clearing cache etc.

It is causing me issues when testing websites, as they work fine on other machines or browsers

Comment: I'm struck by this issue too, on my project, currently checking whether it's Cloudflare related, have you found a lead?

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit), without using Cloudflare at all. I see this even when access resources from an internal webserver over an internal network. Very frustrating!!

Comment: Yeah I never found a solution - I'm now a firefox user

Answer (score 25):

In my case a tool called **Dell SupportAssist** has cleaned up browser caches by deleting their temp folder contents, meanwhile the browser had database entries to those cached files somewhere else and thought the cached data is still available.

> **Solution was to delete those references to inexisting files by cleaning the browser cache within Chrome**

Comment: In my case, Norton 360 has cleaned up my browser caches, and it was causing the issue as explained above. If you are getting ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE error, you should check if you have some software which cleans up browser caches.

Comment: Thanks Norton 360 was exactly my problem too! This issue was driving me crazy, even cleaning everything and reinstalling Chrome wasn't helping and I was truly stumped but lived with the issue for months since although it's annoying as _ it was never actually blocking me from using Chrome. Then I finally found this little sub-comment that I missed several times before. For anyone else using Norton 360, go to:
Settings -> Task Scheduling -> Automatic Tasks -> Chrome Temporary Files

Answer (score 22):

In my case, **Norton 360** was deleting the temp Chrome files.

1. Right-click on the **Norton** icon from the **taskbar**
2. Open Norton 360
3. Settings
4. Tasks Scheduling
5. Uncheck the **'Chrome Temp Files'**
6. Apply

Comment: In my version of Norton 360 there appears to be no option to disable those tasks. I can run it manually, which is the only thing I can do from that menu. There's no checkbox or context menu available for the tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Update:
**This flag is no longer available.**

---

Try typing in chrome url bar: `chrome://flags/#enable-simple-cache-backend`,

Then enable **Simple Cache for HTTP**.

[image]

Reference to google forum with the issue ([link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xJIZFMcyW7Y)).

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems this flag no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem some years ago and fixed it changing dynamically the name of the elements I needed to prevent from being cached, this is how it works.

I defined a variable getting its value by the integer format of the current datetime (you can put whatever you want), that variable was attached to the source path of my elements to be used

This can be a JavaScript...

```
var cacheVersion = new Date().getTime();
```

This is how you include the variable...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${styleSheet}?${cacheVersion}">
<img src="${imagePath}?${cacheVersion}">
```

... etc.

Having extra text after '?' does not modifies the file location.

The point is that when the file name changes the browser is forced to reload it no matter what it cached before or what browser you are using.

[image]

Enjoy!